# How to get an unmodifiableLinkedHashSet

Tags: java, collections, java-8

There are `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` and `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` but no `Collections.unmodifiableLinkedHashSet()`

What is the correct choice for preserving the order?

Comment: The _unmodifiable_ is a wrapper. Just wrap a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: But with what method? I guess if they took the time to place all this Collections.unmodifiableX(collection) is becase it has implications in behind

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet<String>());`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Set` returned by [`Collections.unmodifiableSet(Set)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-) is just a wrapper of the `Set` you provide as an argument.

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified set. This method allows
>   modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal sets.
>   Query operations on the returned set "read through" to the specified
>   set, and attempts to modify the returned set, whether direct or via
>   its iterator, result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

In other words, all *read* activities behave the exact same way as if you were accessing your target `Set` directly. All *write* activities fail.

So just use it with your `LinkedHashSet`.

```
LinkedHashSet<?> someSet = ...
Set<?> wrapper = Collections.unmodifiableSet(someSet);
```